# Can't see Mopub ads

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mopub

I am using MoPub plugin for Unity3D. When I use their default test ad ID which comes in along with the plugin, I can see the test ads perfectly.

But when I create a new ad unit (banner ad), using my own account, and use the new ad ID, I can't see any ad in Android device. The logcat output shows that the ad is received and loaded and getting displayed. Also in console the I can see ad requests.

Is there any settings I've to do? Have anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

err.. Sorry the problem was with the country. There was no ads in my country to show. I just checked with VPN, set my country to USA and there were ads :-)
I had the same problem in Revmob, so tried this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Could you please help me how to set country as USA?

Comment: You need to use VPN, to fool MoPub that you are using the app from USA, not from your current country.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the ad is the correct size? I've seen some problems where the ad wouldn't get loaded because of the ad seemingly being to large for your screen. Remind that the device's sizes are different when you have it in landscape mode.

Comment: Yeah they are of correct size. I am using portrait orientation, so there shouldn't be any problem.